# What is the danger of the "FTP RNFR ././ attempt"?

Tags: forensics, snort, ftp

I am analysing an old attack and I got a scenario which does not really make sense to me.

The attacker connects to the ftp service and runs a bunch "FTP RNFR ././ attempt". This is caught by snort as alert with sid 1:1622 
I do not understand why attacker does that. His next step is PWD followed by CWD (snort sid 1:1672)

I do not understand the steps and the purpose of them by the attacker, what he was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The attacker was trying to exploit the [CVE-1999-0081](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-1999-0081) vulnerability of unpatched [WU-FTPD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WU-FTPD) installations, where a software bug allows `RNFR` *Rename From* commands to overwrite or rename files, even if these commands are violating file permissions and when an unescaped input parameter using relative path pointing to directory root (`././`) is used. The following commands (`PWD` *Print Working Directory*, and `CWD` *Change Working Directory*) suggest the exploit attempt was unsuccessful, otherwise the `RNFR` (*Rename From* specifying a file to rename) would most probably be followed by `RNTO` (*Rename To*) command (probably to rename the root path and remove file permissions on the whole FTP directory structure?). The attacker then retrieved his current position within your FTP directories structure (`PWD`) and navigated to another location within it (`CWD`). `CWD` however takes an argument for the new location, so I can't say what his next step might have been based on information you provide.